# Bug in pluggable.php?

Tags: pluggable

Can anyone help out here?

For several months by now, we start getting problems right after bringing up our website. 
*(we had to restore old pluggable.php to avoid this error)*

> Fatal error:
>   Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Invalid address: ' in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas14_data01/89/3058689/html/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php:946 
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /home/content/p3pnexwpnas14_data01/89/3058689/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php(352): PHPMailer->setFrom('', 'WordPress')
>    - 1 /home/content/p3pnexwpnas14_data01/89/3058689/html/wp-content/themes/enigma-parallax/header.php(99): wp_mail('billmiao.usa@gm...', 'You have new en...', '\n cyberantigens...', 'From: <>\r\nRepl...')
>    - 2 /home/content/p3pnexwpnas14_data01/89/3058689/html/wp-includes/template.php(572): require_once('/home/content/p...')
>    - 3 /home/content/p3pnexwpnas14_data01/89/3058689/html/wp-includes/template.php(531): load_template('/home/content/p...', true)
>    - 4 /home/content/p3pnexwpnas14_data01/89/3058689/html/wp-includes/general-template.php(45): locate_template(Array, true)
>    - 5 /home/content/p3pnexwpnas14_data01/89/3058689/html/wp-content/themes/enigma-parallax/front-page.php(1): get_header()
>    - 6 /home/content/p3pnexwpnas14_data in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas14_data01/89/3058689/html/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php on line 946

I was told that the problem appears - *"old code sets the FromAddress property directly, where the new code calls the setFrom method instead, which throws the exception. The old code will be failing silently."*

How can I get contact info of this file's maintainers?

Thank you all so much in advance for your help/reply.

Bill

Comment: I am using your this site for the 1st time. I used answer to reply. My mistake. How can i follow up on MacPrawn's answer?

Comment: Leave a comment on that answer, and/or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the maintainers of the file are the WordPress team - this is a core WordPress file. : )

That being said, the code is not the problem here, per say. I'm not sure how the old file worked around the issue, but the problem is that you're trying to send an email without a "from" address - and you can't send emails without a "from" email address.

From the logs you posted, the culprit seems to be the theme file "enigma-parallax/header.php" -- on line 99, it seems like there might have been a spot to set a "From" email address, and that was not done, or not done properly? (you rlogs show "'From: <>\r\nRepl...'")

If you can;t isolate the issue in there, please post the code of the "enigma-parallax/header.php" file so we can better help you out.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mac or concerned others - can you see my follow up? This is my 1st time using this site.